# VBA range class failed

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to copy from one workbook to a specific worksheet in another workbook but I keep getting Run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of range class failed.
This is my code below. The error is here ( Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues). Can someone help me please

```
Range("A1").Select
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "K:\HSC LTD 2019-2020\Tools\Sales _ HSC LRM Invoice template\HSCLRM 2020\Fee Report 130120 to 160120.xlsm"
Range("M3:P63").Select
Selection.Copy
   ActiveWindow.Close
    Worksheets("Paste Data").Activate

Range("A1").Activate

Range("A1").Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/9758194) post will probably get you there =)

Comment: I'm guessing that closing the window clears the clipboard.

Comment: Maybe. Should I don't close the window ?